Grout in shower floor is worn up. How can I repair?
Recent homeowner, I am dealing with my own set of TODOs in term of repairing what needs to be repaired. My latest finding is grout on our shower floor that is starting to give and I'm concerned it might start leaking soon.
Important to note that the shower wall tiles all connect to the rest of the bathroom. As in, there is no clean cut between shower walls and rest of bathroom walls. See pictures. Meaning, if I need to retile the whole shower, I'd need to retile the whole bathroom, which I would rather avoid.
Other note: I don't feel like removing the grout in between those tiles to redo it, while take ages for a subpar result still.
How would you repair such a thing?




Please define what it means if the grout is starting to" give".  Also the grout and tile are just a "first defense",  A properly built shower will have another barrier to any moisture that weeps under the tiles.   Still I understand your desire to fix the grout. I am needing a better idea of what is happening beyond the term "give".

Scraping out the grout and reinstalling it is the fix. You can shortcut it if you like, but it probably won't last.

RMDman - The grout is cracked in multiple places. Water's probably not flowing through yet but eventually, it will. I'm sure there is a barrier under it as you mentioned.
Isherwood - the problem is that it's gonna take forever to remove the group in between tiles of this shape. I'd actually like to replace the tiles by something easier to work with in the future.

I think you're implying that you don't expect to be able to match the existing tile with new tile. That's reasonable. The solution is usually to just put in a transition of some sort, like an opposing row of tile, and carry on. You could also rotate all the tile in the repaired area. This is a apparently now a design question, though, which is off topic.

So the grout is cracking. It probably was not mixed properly or was the wrong type of grout.  I have had luck with a wire wheel in a drill. It knocked out most of the loose or weak grout.  First use some bleach product to clean out the mold and mildew. Then let the floor dry before using the wire wheel. Then regrout with a quality un-sanded grout.

A wood-frame exterior wall has an outdoor finish including a water barrier layer and a cladding of brick, stone, stucco, siding, or similar. The cladding does shed bulk water but its job is not to be waterproof. The purpose of the cladding is architectural - it looks nice - and it protects the true water barrier from UV, impact, and other damage.
Tile and grout in a shower are similar. If the shower is built well these shed bulk water, look nice, and protect the water barrier layer beneath them. So, if the concern is over the risk of water damage due to failing grout, the concern might be a little over blown.
It is important to keep the grout in good repair so that an excess of water does not penetrate beneath the tile and grout. This might cause other problems such as mildew/mold or shortened life of the rest of the tile and grout, and it could enable some leaking and damage if the water barrier layer is not perfect.
It's also important that the grout be semi permeable. When water does get behind the tile and grout it needs a way to get out again. Water (liquid or vapor) can't pass through the glazed surface of the tiles but it can permeate through grout. I think it would be a mistake to use something non-cementitious (silicone caulk, for example) as a repair or replacement for failed grout.
It seems like your best repair option is to replace the grout piecemeal by cleaning up specific small areas, perhaps with a rotary tool and grinding bit, and place new grout in those spots. It won't be as pretty but it's quicker and less effort compared to replacing all the grout.
Other than that.. a floor replacement might not be so bad, and it may be possible to do the floor only while leaving the wall intact if wall condition is good enough.

Thank you for your response. This is very informative. And my guess is you are right, my worries were unwarranted due to lack of building knowledge. I have seen no signs of water infiltration anywhere. So it's purely aesthetic. The wall tiles aren't looking great at the bottom. Builders did a bad job with tiles at the bottom as you can see. Which means, it own't be easy to redo the floor only. Might just scrap and re-grout. Thanks!

Accepting your answer as it's been the most informative one. Thank you again!


I don't feel like removing the grout in between those tiles to redo it

Well, then you hire someone else to redo it. That is how to fix a grout problem, if it's a grout problem. If it's a larger problem and the tile is coming up due to poor adhesion, that's a different issue. If you want a totally different shower, that's also a different issue. Grout saws are made to remove just the grout. Yes, it will be painstaking with this pattern, so you'll either pay someone a considerable amount to do it or spend quite some time DIY-ing it.

Makes total sense. I guess I might have to just do it, grout after grout :) Thank you for your answer.
